# Issue in deleting individual element of a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, destructor

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
class Test
{
  public:
  Test (){  cout<<"Const\n"; }
  ~Test (){  cout<<"Dest\n"; }
};
int main( )
{
    vector<Test *> tVec;
    tVec.push_back(new Test());
    tVec.push_back(new Test());
    tVec.insert(tVec.end(),new Test());
    tVec.emplace(tVec.end(),new Test[4]);
    vector<Test *>::iterator it;
    for(it = tVec.begin(); it != tVec.end(); it++)
    {
         delete *it;
         it = tVec.erase(it);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

OUTPUT:

Const
Const
Const
Const
Const
Const
Const
Dest
Dest

Only two destructor has been called , while 8 constructor has been called . I know the last four object I created as an array . Is there any generic way to delete the individual objects inside vector . Second How to access these individual array element .

Comment: for `new []` you need to call `delete []` you cannot get around this, so turn every pointer into a pointer to array (e.g. `vector<vector<T>>`) or have two vectors

Comment: why do you store pointers in the vector? The fact that you want to delete them manually indicates that you actually dont need pointers (You would need pointers if the objects are owned by someone else and in that case the vector doesnt care about deleting them).

Answer (score 3):

(Formally the behaviour of your program is *undefined*: you must **never** mix `new[]` with `delete`: every `new` must be balanced with a `delete`, and every `new[]` balanced with `delete[]`.)

The interaction of `it = tVec.erase(it);` with the `it++` in the `for` loop is giving you gyp. (The iterator returned by `erase` is *already* the next one).

You're missing out every other vector element.

Remove the increment statement from the `for` loop (my preferred choice) and all will be well.

As for a *generic* way, if you were to use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Test>>` instead, then the considerably simpler and more reliable `tVec.clear()` would do the job. Or use `std::vector<Test>` and use (i) emplacement and (ii) trust in your compiler, to obviate any value copies.

Comment: But as @BeyelerStudios said, you still need to handle the array... I vote for the std::unique_ptr

Comment: For arrays, the easy way would be to use std::shared_ptr and provide an array custom deleter when necessary (shared_ptr holds the deleter).

Answer (score 1):

Here a version which will really call all destructors including arrays:

```
void ArrayDeleter(Test *t) {
    delete[] t;
};

int main()
{
    vector<shared_ptr<Test> > tVec;
    tVec.push_back(make_shared<Test>());
    tVec.push_back(make_shared<Test>());
    tVec.insert(tVec.end(), make_shared<Test>());
    tVec.emplace(tVec.end(), shared_ptr<Test>(new Test[4], ArrayDeleter));
    tVec.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

Still, the ArrayDeleter must be passed explicitly, otherwise it will not work indeed.